# Delphi TMapView: Any way to turn off zoom on doubletap?

Tags: ios, delphi, maps, firemonkey

I am using a TMapView component in a Firemonkey project. I have eventhandlers that fire when a user double clicks on a marker (and also a separate event for single click). However, everytime double tap on a marker the map automatically zooms, in addition to firing my event. I've been looking through the doucmentation, but I have yet to find a property or method that handles this. So, is there any way to turn off this feature in TMapView.

Comment: Removing `Zoom` from the `GestureOptions` option set wouldn't help?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, no, I've tried this. While it does kind of help, in that there is no zooming anymore, it is also an issue, since there is no zooming at all anymore. This project is on iOS, so there are no + and - buttons for zooming like there is on fmx projects in Android. Removing Zoom from GestureOptions renders the app unable to use the fingers to zoom in and out. I still need zoom capability, I just wand to get rid of the autozoom on double tap.